# Web config error with two databases in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I develop a website and there are two databases in my web site. 
I made two database and users in plesk panel and upload the back ups,
database the first name is database_Journal and database name 2 is database_General and also the users are UserID1 and UserID.
But there is some thing wrong in it and it gave me this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My web config is like this:

```
 <add name="dbconn" connectionString="Password==******;; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserID1; Initial Catalog=database_General; Data Source=***.**.**.**" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>

    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Password=******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserID1; Initial Catalog=database_General; Data Source=***.**.**.**" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <add name="dbconn_general" connectionString="Password==******;; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserID; Initial Catalog=database_Journal; Data Source=***.**.**.**" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this format...

```
<add name="dbconn" connectionString="server=YourServerNameOrServerIpAddress; database=database_General; uid=UserID1; Password=******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```